# images are not loading in the view laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-blade

images was working just fine, my collaborateur in git messed the project up , so i'am now using the recovery project and images are not showing anymore 
here's my code everything was working

my store method

```
 if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('public/avatars', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }







        $member = new Member;
   // others attributes 

        $member->avatar = $fileNameToStore;

        $member->save();
```

my view file

```
<div class="image-container">
                <img src="/storage/avatars/{{$member->avatar}}" class="avatar img-responsive" alt="avatar">
            </div>
```

its show no erros , the files are in the correct folder after the create but images are not showing

Comment: Change `src="/storage/avatars/{{$member->avatar}}"` to `src="/public/avatars/{{$member->avatar}}"`

Comment: @TalhaF. dont work

Comment: Where you saved your images?

Comment: @TalhaF. storage/app/public/avatars

Comment: i created manualy avatars folder in my public/storage and now images are laoding , but when i create another user , his pic don't show

Comment: everything was working fine

Comment: Did you create the   symlink `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: @TalhaF.  yes i did

Comment: i delted the folder and recreated the symlink php artisan storage:link?  now it works